# File/folder creation failing in latest Samsung models

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-external-storage

I have an app that takes a file from the assets folder and writes it to external storage for further access. This seems to be working on almost all phones, but the app keeps crashing while trying the same thing in latest Samsung J series and S series phones. Is there any kind of restriction introduced by Samsung that does not allow me to access the external storage?

Comment: The crash dump should tell you where it is crashing.

Comment: What is your target API?@Abhishek Koirala